# How can my website show only links of posts in wordpress and one feature article?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I looked in documentation but have no clue. My goal is that the main div should contain a featured post I choose and under a set of catgeories in a div, it should display links to posts that include a certain tag. HELP?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) that outputs the posts as you described using [custom queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query), create a page that uses this template, then [set your site's home page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) to be this page.